# Why is the maximum horizontal range in a projectile motion given by shooting with an angle of $\pi/4$ inclination about the horizontal direction?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

I've heard sometimes that in projectile motion you need to shoot things with a $\pi/4$ angle in order to get the maximum range, but why does that happen?

In this case I know that

$$x(t) = x_0+v_{0x}t$$

$$y(t) = y_0 +v_{0y}t - \frac12 g t^2$$

How do you conclude that is necessarily $\pi/4$?

Comment: $x$ and $y$ in your equations should be parts of the subscripts of $v$, thus: $v_{0x}$ and $v_{0y}$. [Put 0x and 0y in squiggly brackets when typing them in.] Your next step should be to express $v_{0x}$ and $v_{0y}$ in terms of the angle of launch and the speed of launch.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers given it is worth mentioning that for every distance lesser than the maximum distance there are two solutions to reach that distance: one where the angle is lower (with a flatter parabola) and another where the angle is higher (with a steeper parabola) than $\pi/4$ (=45 degree). When you get closer to $\pi/4$ those two angles get closer and merge to one solution when maximum distance is reached.

(Always assuming the same initial velocity)

Answer (score 0):

The range of a projectile is $R=(u^2\sin 2\theta)/g$, so it is maximum for $\pi/4$

Answer (score 0):

Speaking intuitively, I'll say that if the angle is greater than $\frac{\pi}{4}$ then the particle will have a greater vertical velocity which means that range will decrease. If the angle is less than $\frac{\pi}{4}$ then the particle will have a greater forward velocity which means that it will reach the ground sooner and hence will have less range.

So, we settle at the middle which is $\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Answer (score 0):

You are unnecessarily stretching the problem by adding more variables $(x_0, y_0) $ which you can easily avoid by shifting the origin since range of a projectile is function of only velocity $(v)$ and angle $(\theta)$ of projection.

Hence, substitute $v_x=v\cos\theta$ and $v_y=v\sin\theta$ and eliminate $t$. Now, you have to maximize the resultant expression.